# I try to write a condition in thymeleaf with OR

Tags: thymeleaf

I need to have a condition with logical operator OR. I try to do in this way but it seem doesn't work :

```
  <div th:if="${(fingerprints.totalPages != 0) or (fingerprints.totalPages != 1)}"
```

How I suppose to do ? :)

Comment: why it doesn't work? any errors?

Comment: I did this in the past but I think I used double-lines "||". In JSP-Pages expression language allows "or". I don't know if thymeleaf do so, too.

Comment: Aside, but you may just be better off simplifying to `th:if="${fingerprints.totalPages} &gt; 1"` if that satisfies your needs.  I'm assuming you won't care about negative or fractional pages.

Answer (score 0):

Both `or` and `||` work.  In this case, your logic is wrong.  I think your expression should be:

```
th:if="${(fingerprints.totalPages != 0) and (fingerprints.totalPages != 1)}"
```

Your original expression is always true. (Since fingerprints.totalPages is always going to be either `!= 1` or `!= 0`.